# Two passes to mark occurrences in syntax tree?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Let's say you had a syntax tree that contains--among other things--nodes representing identifiers.  Something like:

```
type node = ...
| Ident of string
...
```

I want to walk the tree, and mark all Ident nodes with the number of occurrences of that identifier.  For example, if the identifier "x" occurs 3 times in the tree, each of the Ident "x" nodes would be "marked" with a 3.

Clearly, this would require a modification of the type decl to accommodate the new data (someting like "Ident of string * ref int").  My question is what is the best approach to do this?  Seems like a two-pass approach one doing the counting and one doing the "marking" might be the most straightforward, but even then, it seems it would be awkward to keep track of the nodes for a given identifier.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why modify *all* identifier nodes anyway? That's excessively redundant, and not much more convenient than a `string -> int` map along the side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a purely functional solution:

```
type 'a exp = Ident of 'a | Const of int | Add of 'a exp * 'a exp

(* pass 1: count occurrences of identifiers *)
let count : string exp -> (string * int) list =
  let rec record x = function
    | [] -> [(x, 1)]
    | (y, n) :: counts when x = y -> (y, n + 1) :: counts
    | count :: counts -> count :: record x counts
  in
  let rec visit acc = function
    | Ident x -> record x acc
    | Const _ -> acc
    | Add (e1, e2) -> visit (visit acc e1) e2
  in
  visit []

(* pass 2: mark all identifiers with their occurrence counts *)
let mark (counts : (string * int) list) : string exp -> (string * int) exp =
  let rec lookup x = function
    | [] -> invalid_arg "lookup"
    | (y, n) :: _ when x = y -> n
    | _ :: counts -> lookup x counts
  in
  let rec visit = function
    | Ident x -> Ident (x, lookup x counts)
    | Const n -> Const n
    | Add (e1, e2) -> Add (visit e1, visit e2)
  in
  visit

(* combining the two passes *)
let mark_with_counts e = mark (count e) e
```

Note that the two passes can be merged into a single visit function, effectively avoiding the repeated pattern matching:

```
let mark_with_counts' e =
  let rec record x = function
    | [] -> [(x, 1)]
    | (y, n) :: counts when x = y -> (y, n + 1) :: counts
    | count :: counts -> count :: record x counts
  in
  let rec lookup x = function
    | [] -> invalid_arg "lookup"
    | (y, n) :: _ when x = y -> n
    | _ :: counts -> lookup x counts
  in
  let rec visit acc = function
    | Ident x -> (record x acc, fun counts -> Ident (x, lookup x counts))
    | Const n -> (acc, fun _ -> Const n)
    | Add (e1, e2) ->
        let (acc, syn1) = visit acc e1 in
        let (acc, syn2) = visit acc e2 in
        (acc, fun counts -> Add (syn1 counts, syn2 counts))
  in
  let (counts, syn) = visit [] e in
  syn counts
```